# Is it possible to transform characters in a preprocessor directive?

Tags: c++, macros

The problem is simple. I want the macro `MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(type)` to generate an instance of `SuperVector<type>`. I want this instances to have a specific name. So for example, if my type is an `int`, I want it to be called `supervector_of_int_`. The problem is, if my type is somewhat more complicated, like for example, a class inside a namespace or some template class, I am not able to create such instance. For the case (in the example) of `ns::C`, I want to create a `SuperVector<ns::C>` called `supervector_of_ns__C_` for example. The case of using `std::vector<int>` as my type is not that important for me but it would be nice to know.

I tried to keep it as simple as possible. Assume the macro `GET_SUPER_VECTOR` is important and cannot be erased.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class SuperVector : public std::vector<T> {
    // Whatever...
};

namespace ns {
    class C {
        int x;
    };
}

#define GET_SUPER_VECTOR(type) supervector_of_ ## type ## _
#define MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(type) SuperVector<type> GET_SUPER_VECTOR(type)
MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(int);
MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(ns::C);
MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(std::vector<int>);

int main() {

}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
program.cc:17:34: error: pasting ">" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(std::vector<int>);
                                  ^
program.cc:13:51: note: in definition of macro ‘GET_SUPER_VECTOR’
 #define GET_SUPER_VECTOR(type) supervector_of_ ## type ## _
                                                   ^~~~
program.cc:17:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR’
 MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(std::vector<int>);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

program.cc:13:32: error: ‘supervector_of_ns’ has not been declared
 #define GET_SUPER_VECTOR(type) supervector_of_ ## type ## _
                                ^
program.cc:14:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘GET_SUPER_VECTOR’
 #define MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(type) SuperVector<type> GET_SUPER_VECTOR(type)
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
program.cc:16:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR’
 MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(ns::C);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
program.cc:13:32: error: ‘supervector_of_std’ has not been declared
 #define GET_SUPER_VECTOR(type) supervector_of_ ## type ## _
                                ^
program.cc:14:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘GET_SUPER_VECTOR’
 #define MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(type) SuperVector<type> GET_SUPER_VECTOR(type)
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
program.cc:17:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR’
 MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(std::vector<int>);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
program.cc:17:30: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(std::vector<int>);
                              ^
program.cc:13:51: note: in definition of macro ‘GET_SUPER_VECTOR’
 #define GET_SUPER_VECTOR(type) supervector_of_ ## type ## _
                                                   ^~~~
program.cc:17:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR’
 MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(std::vector<int>);
```

Comment: It's impossible. If you explain why you need this macro, we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I need it to store some information of (around ten) different types of objects. In my case, what the objects have in common is that they have an id that identifies them, and therefore I want to work with all of them in a way that all those containers of objects are treated in a similar way between themselves

Comment: Maybe you want variable templates? `template <typename T> SuperVector<T> super_vector;` Then you can use it as e.g. `super_vector<int>`, and you don't need `MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat WOW I did not know such thing existed, thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

The result of the macro-pasting must be a valid identifier.

And `supervector_of_std::vector<int>` is not a valid identifier.

You could give the macro a second parameter for the acutal indentifier like:

`#define MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR(type, identname ) SuperVector<type> GET_SUPER_VECTOR(identname)`

Then call it like this:
`MAKE_SUPER_VECTOR( std::vector<int>, std_vector_int );`